# Android Gradle: How to run one task after another

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I need to run a copy task after an NPM install task in an android gradle build script.

```
task getTokens(type: NpmTask) {
    args = ['install', '--save @myTokens/tokens-assemble-android@latest;']
    doLast {
        copyColors
    }
}

task copyColors(type: Copy) {
    from '${projectDir}/../node_modules/@myTokens/tokens/colorTokens.kt'
    into '${projectDir}/tokens'
}
```

The NpmTask runs (sometimes) but the copyColors task does not (ever). Ive tried shouldRunAfter, mustRunAfter, doLast, copyColors.dependsOn(getTokens), and more. I'm pretty confused by the ever changing syntax and multiple ways to do things in gradle scripting. All I need is one way that works. Do I need to use the tasks.register syntax? Any advice?